# Given program for replace string with sequence of number should be written in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello everyone  i have a program that read the csv file and replace the string to squence of number and it have other column like date/time which is have to print date
only for all operation this program working very well but i want to this program in Pandas dataframe please can somebody take this code and use all operation for pandas
i have less knowledge in pandas i would very greatfull to you..Thank

**This is the code**

```
with open(tempFile, 'r',encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        # creating a csv reader object 
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    #     next(reader, None)

        '''We then restructure the data to be a set of keys with list of values {key_1: [], key_2: []}:'''        
        data = {}
        for row in reader:
    #         print(row)
            for header, value in row.items():
                try:
                    data[header].append(value)
                except KeyError:
                    data[header] = [value]

        '''Next we want to give each value in each list a unique identifier.'''            
        # Loop through all keys
        for key in data.keys():
            values = data[key]

            things = list(sorted(set(values), key=values.index))

            for i, x in enumerate(data[key]):
        if data[key][i] == "":
           data[key][i] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

with open('ram5.csv', "w") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        # Write headers
        writer.writerow(data.keys())
        # Make one row equal to one value from each list
        rows = zip(*data.values())
        # Write rows
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

**This is the input data:**

```
job_Id      Name        Address     Email            Date/Time
1        snehil singh   marathalli  ss@gmail.com     12/10/2011:02:03:20
2        salman         marathalli  ss@gmail.com     12/11/2011:03:10:20
3        Amir           HSR         ar@gmail.com    
4        Rakhesh        HSR         rakesh@gmail.com 09/12/2010:02:03:55
5        Ram            marathalli  r@gmail.com 
6        Shyam          BTM         ss@gmail.com     12/11/2012:01:03:20
7        salman         HSR         ss@gmail.com    
8        Amir           BTM         ar@gmail.com     07/10/2013:04:02:30
9        snehil singh   Majestic    sne@gmail.com    03/03/2018:02:03:20
```

**This is the desired output:**

```
job_Id  Name    Address Email   Date/Time

1      1       1       1    12/10/2011

2      2       1       1    12/11/2011

3      3       2       2    11/02/2018

4      4       2       3    09/12/2010

5      5       1       4    11/02/2018

6      6       3       1    12/11/2012

7      2       2       1    11/02/2018

8      3       3       2    07/10/2013

9      1       4       5    03/03/2018
```

**Note: the empty date/time column is replaced with the current date** ...so in this program i'm getting all the desired data correct and the above output is the output for the program i have written.
**but want to write a entire program by using the Pandas dataframe**..please help guys any help will be appreciable..thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `str[0]` for select first lists and replace by datetime converted to strings by [`Timestamp.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html):

```
now = pd.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['Date/Time'] = df['Date/Time'].str.split(':').str[0].fillna(now)
```

Alternative is convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), replace missing values to now and last convert it to strings by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Date/Time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
                     .fillna(pd.datetime.now())
                     .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

And then use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for processes multiple columns:

```
cols = ['Name','Address','Email']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1)
print (df)
   job_Id  Name  Address  Email   Date/Time
0       1     1        1      1  12/10/2011
1       2     2        1      1  12/11/2011
2       3     3        2      2  02/11/2018
3       4     4        2      3  09/12/2010
4       5     5        1      4  02/11/2018
5       6     6        3      1  12/11/2012
6       7     2        2      1  02/11/2018
7       8     3        3      2  07/10/2013
8       9     1        4      5  03/03/2018
```

Comment: thnx for the solution it is working for the name,address, email not for the date

Comment: @rahulsingh - there is some error? Can you explain more?

Comment: i'm reading a csv file in which column name date/time which contain like 12/10/2011:02:03:20 but in my program i have convted it to show only date like 12/10/2011 also replaced empty date with current date now im getting error like ValueError: time data '12/10/2011' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: Sir i have edited in the same program you have given please see it and tell me where i'm doing wrong  im getting error like ValueError: time data '12/10/2011' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: @rahulsingh - only change `%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S` to `%d/%m/%Y`.

Comment: Sir shall i ask you other than this code .....i want to become very good in Pandas dataframe like you.... how do i prepare it and apply for practical knowledge coze online only have theory things not practical problem and very less examples so can u please tell me any site who can help me inprove my skills so i can do more practical things in dataframe

Comment: @rahulsingh - Reall hard and not exist easy solution. You have to code a lot, also I believe you can check [tutorials](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#lessons-for-new-pandas-users) for start.